# How to properly collect and manage admin media files from django?

Tags: django, django-admin

Collecting the admin-media files from different django application is one of the not-so-good things about django. Usually you have to file copying from the module distributions to your directory every time one you install/update/remove a module.

When you are using several django application that do have their own media/admin files, some of them even overriding others you need a proper way of collecting them and building a correct media directory.

A proper solution should be able to recreate the directory by collecting the required files 
from the modules in a specific order, allowing them to override each other.

Useful links

- [Proposal: installmedia command - A story for distributing media with apps](https://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/94efe43b1d1c7787/1178b2ee48791612?#1178b2ee48791612)

**What solution do you have for this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment the best solution I found was to use http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1068/ 
but I'm still looking for better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I just stack multiple `Alias` directives one on top of each other, grafting the media to the appropriate place on the tree.